# Mgo single bson.M result not properly working

Tags: go, bson, mgo

I am building a resource REST api and have a problem with following

the Find method that return all records is working fine like this

```
type Resource struct {
  *Controller
}

func (self *Resource) Find(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  resource := self.ParseResource(req)
  queryParams := req.URL.Query()
  query := make(bson.M, 0)
  for k, v := range queryParams {
    query[k] = v[0]
 }

var jsonR []bson.M
  coll := self.GetDb().C(resource)
  coll.Find(query).All(&jsonR)
  self.RenderJson(res, jsonR)
}
```

The single result is not working, returning a empty struct:

```
func (self *Resource) FindOne(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  id := mux.Vars(req)["id"]
  var jsonR = bson.M{}
  coll := self.GetDb().C(self.ParseResource(req))
  query := bson.M{"_id": id}
  coll.Find(query).One(&jsonR)
  self.RenderJson(res, jsonR)
}
```

I know the problem is somewhere in var jsonR = bson.M{} but it works fine in findall 
any idea what i missing?

Comment: Although this is orthogonal to your question, this/self aren't common in Go: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#methods

Answer (score 0):

Fully working code, the problem whas the bson.ObjectIdHex(id) instead of just id

```
func (self *Resource) FindOne(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
      id := mux.Vars(req)["id"]
      raw := req.URL.String()
      raw = strings.TrimPrefix(raw, "/")
      resource := strings.TrimSuffix(raw, "/" + id)

      var jsonR bson.M
      coll := self.GetDb().C(resource)
      err := coll.FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex(id)).One(&jsonR)
      if err != nil {
        panic(err)
      }
      self.RenderJson(res, jsonR)
    }
```